# Arithmetic operation

Tags: arithmetic, binary-operations

Given
$$9 ∆ 4=20,$$
$$7 ∆ 3=12,$$
$$10 ∆ 8=16,$$
find $m ∆ n$.

I have tried so many ways to get this but I may be missing something.

Comment: Subtract and multiply.

Comment: Blind guessing yields $(m-n)\times n$.  But it's kind of random.

Comment: Thanks a lot...makes sense

Answer (score 1):

As @lulu said in comments, it's mainly a guessing idea.

I noticed that the second number was divisible by the answer. $\frac{20}{4}=5, \frac{12}{3}=4$, et cetera. So one would think that a multiplication of $n$ would be involved. From there, it's just a matter of what to multiply by. Trying it out leads to $$(m-n)\cdot n.$$